# Is 4th root of $-1$ the same as $i^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am using mathway to check my algebra problems and tried entering in the 4th root of $-1$ (or $(-1)^{1/4}$.   I get the same term back, but I thought that since the square root of $-1$ is $i$, that the answer should be $i^2$ given that 
$$
(-1)^{1/4} 
= (-1)^{1/2} * (-1)^{1/2}
= i * i
= i^2 $$

Would someone please confirm whether my reasoning is correct?  Unfortunately my textbook doesn't go into complex numbers at length and the web resources don't sufficiently cover nth roots of negative 1.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Exponents with the same base add!

Comment: $(-1)^\frac{1}{4}\not=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot (-1)^{\frac{1}{2}}=(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}=-1$.

Comment: Impossible, since $\mathrm i^2=-1$. You must use the exponential form

Comment: No $(-1)^{\frac{1}{4}}=\sqrt {i}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}+i \frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$

Comment: $(-1)^{1/4}$ must have for results

Comment: Before any computation mistake creeps in, there is a more fundamental problem, which is that no function $z\mapsto z^{1/4}$ can be defined canonically on the complex plane.

Comment: You don't even have to mess with 4th roots to check whether this is true. If you raise $i^2$ to the $4$th power, do you get $-1$? If not, it's *not* a fourth root of $-1$, by the very definition of a fourth root.

Answer (score 7):

Let's try applying that logic in a more familiar setting:
$$
16^{1/4} \overset{?}= 16^{1/2}\times 16^{1/2} = 4 \times 4 = 4^2
$$
Perhaps now you can see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 2):

First notice that $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \pm i$ and $i^2 = -1$. It is a common mistake to think that $(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}} = i$.

And your second mistake only has to do with powers: $x^{a+b} = x^{a}x^{b}$ but $x^{a\cdot b} = (x^{a})^b \neq x^{a}x^b$

Your third mistake: $x^{a+b} = x^{a}x^{b}$ is not always true in the complex plane. See below.

Comment: Good to remind the rule $x^{a+b}=x^ax^b$. Even better would be to note that it is not always true in the complex plane.

Comment: @Did  can you give an example?

Comment: Sure: $i=e^{i\pi/2}=e^{5i\pi/2}$ but $e^{i\pi/4}e^{5i\pi/4}\ne i$.

Comment: @Did sorry, I don't get it.  $e^{i\pi/4}e^{5i\pi/4} = \frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}} \frac{-1-i}{\sqrt{2}} = - \frac{1}{2} (1+i)^2 =- \frac{1}{2} (1+2i +i^2) = -i $ and  $e^{i\pi/4}e^{5i\pi/4} = e^{i3\pi/2} = -i$

Comment: Yeah but $i^{1/2}i^{1/2}$ is supposed to equal $i$ while in your comment you "compute" it as $-i$... What this example is pointing at is that there is no way to define unambiguously a function $z\mapsto z^a$ on the whole complex plane, except if $a$ is an integer.

Comment: ah yes, now I remember. thanks for your patients :)

Answer (score 0):

Either you use the expoential form: $\mathrm i=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\pi}$,hence the fourth roots of $-1$ are the complex numbers $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\theta}$, with
$$4\theta\equiv \pi\mod 2\pi,\enspace\text{whence}\enspace\theta\equiv \frac\pi4\mod\frac\pi2.$$

Alternatively, anyone having made some computations with complex numbers knows $(1+\mathrm i)^2=2i$, hence $(1+\mathrm i)^4=-4$, so that a fourth root of $-1$ is:
$$\frac{1+\mathrm i}{\sqrt2}.$$
The other roots are obtained, as usual, multiplying this one with the fourth roots of $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers pointed out your mistake in splitting the exponential. The more interesting part is, that a $4$th root in the complex plane formally has $4$ solutions. Actually, you are finding the solutions of the polynomial $z^4=-1$ which can easily be solved in the polar form, as $z=e^{(i\pi+2n\pi)/4}$ for $n=0,1,2,3$ and cyclically repeating. If you are not familiar with this notation, just write $z=a+bi$ and find all $4$ solutions by hand.